# The widgets are not showing when I click run module for my code

Tags: python, button, tkinter, widget

I have attached my code so that you can all see if you can identify the problem. Everything is working, and the window is popping up, but the button widgets are not showing:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
  """Login"""

def _init_(self, master):
          self.master = master

def create_widgets(self):
    btn1 = Button(self.master, text = "Login")
    btn1.pack()

    btn2 = Button(self.master, text = "Sign Up")
    btn2.pack()

    btn3=Button(self.master, text = "Exit")
    btn3.pack()


root = Tk()
root.title("Parent Pool")
root.geometry("500x500")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please make sure the indentation here is the same as it is in your script.

Comment: The indentation is the same here as it is in the original script, but I am only getting the GUI window popping up, but no widgets

Comment: If the code in the question is exactly what is in your script, it won't run at all due to the indentation errors.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to call `create_widgets`. And your `def`s need to be indented inside the class.

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    """Login"""

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

    def create_widgets(self):
        btn1 = Button(self.master, text = "Login")
        btn1.pack()

        btn2 = Button(self.master, text = "Sign Up")
        btn2.pack()

        btn3=Button(self.master, text = "Exit")
        btn3.pack()

root = Tk()
root.title("Parent Pool")
root.geometry("500x500")
app = Application(root)
app.create_widgets()
root.mainloop()
```

By the way, your `_init_` function won't get called when you create an Application instance. You need to name it `__init__` if you want that behavior. (Your Buttons can still reference `self.master` even though `_init_` never runs, because `Frame.__init__` gets called as a fallback during instantiation, and creates the master attribute by coincidence)